Constrained invertibility problem with solution over $\mathbb C$ but not over $\mathbb R$?
A constrained invertibility (CI) problem is a triple $(n, P,Q)$ where $n \geq 1$ and $P,Q \subseteq [n] \times [n]$ where $[n]=\{1,\dots , n\}$. The problem asks to find two $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ such that:

$AB=I_n$ = $n\times n$ identity matrix.
$A_{ij}=0$ for all $(i,j) \in P$ and $B_{ij}=0$ for all $(i,j) \in Q$.

Of course the existence of a solution to a CI problem depends on the underlying field.
Consider $\mathbb R \subset \mathbb C$. Of course if a CI problem has a solution over $\mathbb R$, it has one over $\mathbb C$ (trivially). However, it is not clear that a CI problem with a solution over $\mathbb C$ should have a solution over $\mathbb R$.
What are examples of CI problems for, say, $n=3$, that have a solution over $\mathbb C$ but not over $\mathbb R$?
